# Wordpress - Show Meta url as linkable

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I'm creating wordpress website. Below every post is meta box with key: "byline". This meta value is URL. Now this url is not clickable, but I want to create this value as url which will open in new Window. Or just how to create this value to show as url, not like a normal text?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the code on what you have so far, what is used to display the text

Comment: I'm using one plugin for showing meta data, but now I added one Image, and I want to add where is <a href="url"> </a> in URL meta value which I get with :
<?php $byline = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'byline', true ); ?>